# Better technique for MyThread class

Tags: java, multithreading

Better Post : ["implements Runnable" vs. "extends Thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)

I can create my own thread class MyThread two ways,

```
class MyThread extends Thread
or
class MyThread implements Runnable
```

Which technique is better and why?

And in case of implementing Runnable, I have to create Thread object from MyThread object, like

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread();
Thread t = new Thread(mt);
```

then what is the advantage of implementing Runnable Interface technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While creating a thread implementing Runnable interface is better. Because you can extend your new class from other class, otherwise you can not extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a Thread is better if you want to retain some control over the thread's work, like calling `interrup()`. In general, I'd say that extending a `Thread` is OK when the class is some kind of Manger or Worker.

In other cases, especially **when a class represents some work to be done (`Job`, `Future`) it's much better to implement runnable**.

Answer (score 0):

> And in case of implementing Runnable, I have to create Thread object
>   from MyThread object, like

```
MyThread mt = new MyThread();
Thread t = new Thread(mt);
```

**NOT NECESSARILY**

You can do this...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable () { public void run() { /* do stuff */ }});
```

... no need for MyThread class.